# How to use Python from Xamarin

Tags: c#, python, mobile, xamarin

I have a existing application and the code was written in Python. Now i am developing a Mobile application using Xamarin. Now I want to use the same existing application code written in Python to develop my mobile apps from Xamarin. 
How can I use Python from Xamarin.

Comment: To my knowledge I don't think you can. Xamarin is c#

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Xamarin has built bindings from C#/.NET to the underlying languages and runtimes on iOS and Android. That is what it provides for you; you don't have to code in Objective-C or Java but can use C# and get more reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://kivy.org/. Depending on your existing code, maybe it's the quicker way to create an App that runs on iOS and Android and and elsewhere. If not, you'll have two options: Translate your python code to C# or make it accessible over a (restful) API and then use that from your Xamarin App.